# Может ли MMU записывать/считывать данные побайтно или только постранично?

Tags: linux, c, memory-management

Необходимо определить и доказать, каким именно образом работает MMU в данном контексте, а именно:

```
fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC)
map_base = mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, "", offset); 
virt_addr = map_base;
*((unsigned long *) virt_addr) = writeval;
```

Вопрос. Осуществив запись в адрес virt_addr. MMU в физическом пространстве памяти внесет изменение только в адрес virt_addr или же перезапишет страницу с измененным значением virt_addr? И каким образом это доказать?

Comment: Вообще-то MMU транслирует виртуальные адреса в физические, а не пишет в память. В вашем же случае, когда вы пытаетесь писать в память по адресу уже за выделенной областью, вангую будет ошибка (segfault или buserr)

Comment: а вообще запись непосредственно в память будет скорей всего происходить линейками кеша, хотя может и напрямую, но уж точно не страницами... и да, `mmap` и следующая строка вообще как-то странно записаны...

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо за помощь. Код по памяти восстанавливал. А Вы не могли бы сказать, где именно я могу получить точную информацию или как это все доказать ? Пере рыскал кучу литературы и так не нашел ответа.

Comment: @avp, представьте, что я работаю с адресным пространством устройства, допустим SPI. Я получил адрес страниц, произвел в ней изменения и в этот момент в регистрах устройства записались новые значения. Так вот, каким образом произойдет совмещение данных ?

Comment: @Allladin, вы работаете **внутри** kernel? (в комментарии я говорил о syscall mmap в user space, и честно говоря, о принятых внутри linux kernel соглашениях по программирования устройств я не знаю)

Comment: По поводу совмещения данных на физическом уровне. Я думаю, что в регистре флагов MMU модуля (надо читать доку по конкретному MMU) , в котором находится ваш SPI, надо прописать кэш-когерентность (т.е. атрибуты памяти, например в Aarch64 д.б. normal memory, outer memory, cachable, shareable, write back, read-write allocate (опять же, смотреть надо аналоги для конкретно вашей архитектуры))

Comment: С другой стороны (опять же, я не знаю, как это сделано в linux kernel), я бы работал с регистрами устройства напрямую, сделав атрибуты сегмента памяти (в MMU процессора) относящейся к регистрам SPI как device memory. Т.е. в виртуальных адресах процессора у меня была бы страница, которая мапируется на физические адреса, относящиеся к SPI с атрибутами device (а не normal memory). Обращения к такой странице будут проходить мимо кэша.

Comment: @Allladin, я немного подумал и решил, что если `/dev/mem` это реально карта памяти в физических адресах,  флаг `O_SYNC` говорит функции `mmap()` о том, что возвращаемая страница д.б. с атрибутами device memory и offset соответствует базовому адресу SPI, то вы в самом деле получите страничку виртуальной памяти с синхронным доступом к регистрам SPI. / А в приведении адреса я бы написал `(volatile unsigned long *)`, чтобы заставить компилятор  всегда генерить команды записи-чтения памяти при обращении по указателю `virt_addr`

Comment: @avp работаю через user space, я прекрасно понимаю, что лучше всего работать с регистрами через kernel space. Но что если исходников драйверов у вас нет, а только описание регистров устройства и bin драйвера ? Вот и встал такой вопрос. Спасибо. Вы мне помогли.

Comment: @avp, поидей `O_SYNC` ни как не влияет на результат... а вот какие дополнительные телодвижения нужны, чтобы память писалась напрямую, минуя кеш, как минимум, я не знаю — возможно на x86 это происходит автомагически... никаких дополнительных телодвижений в ядре я не вижу, так что у меня есть некоторые сомнения на этот счёт...

Comment: @Allladin, как доказать — не придумаю, но если посмотреть [исходники ядра]( https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/drivers/char/mem.c#L358) в плане реализации `/dev/mem`, то там запрошенные страницы просто мапятся в пользовательское пространство без всяких прекрас... как в них будет происходить запись — зависит от архитектуры... по всей логике процессор должен сам определять эти области памяти и писать в них напрямую, но подтверждения я этому (хотя бы для x86) не нашёл...

Comment: @Allladin, насколько мне известно, пользователь может добавить в ядро свой драйвер через механизм модулей ядра. Не рассматривали такую возможность? И второе, с существующими [драйверами SPI](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/drivers/spi) не пробовали разобраться?

Comment: @Allladin, по поводу проверки доступа к регистрам SPI. Я бы попробовал писать в регистры  **Interrupt Enable Register** / **Interrupt Disable Register** и для проверки доступа читал **Interrupt Mask Register** (см. [тут  'Интерфейс программирования SPI'](http://microsin.net/programming/arm/at91sam7-spi.html))

Comment: @avp, все было очень просто. Чтобы проверить, каким образом записывается информация в память, использовался /dev/mem.  Я записал в буфер SPI данные, прочитал флаг о состоянии буфера. Флаг свидетельствовал о наличии данных. После прочтения из буфера сообщений, состояние флага менялось. Это говорит о том, что значения записывались по адресно.

Comment: @Allladin, здорово! Значит через /dev/mem можно управлять девайсами. А какой у вас комп и линукс?

Comment: @avp да, управлять можно, но не желательно. Комьютер МВ7707 (АО НТЦ МОДУЛЬ), дистрибутив Debian для ARM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На у на самом деле ответ был очень просто, не нужно было так долго копаться и вникать. /dev/mem это символьное устройство, а это значит что обмен данным осуществляется посимвольно.